# Extract values from a multi band raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I currently have a raster with multi-bands.

```
> EVI.all
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  12  bands)
dimensions  : 771, 735, 566685  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.002245788, 0.002245788  (x, y)
extent      : 76.22654, 77.8772, 9.861256, 11.59276  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : E:\Data\EVI\MOD13Q1_EVI_AllYears.tif 
names       : MOD13Q1_EVI_AllYears
```

When I try to extract the values from each band, I am only getting the values of the first band. Any suggestions? Alternately I would like to get multiple rasters - one for each band.

See below:

```
e <-  raster::extract(EVI.all,trial)
> e
  [1] 2924.38889 2924.38889 3157.33333 3952.00000 3336.97222 4052.77778 3169.19444 4226.27778 3621.52778 2732.41667
 [11] 3695.94444 4306.08333 4306.08333 4136.55556 3695.94444 4484.30556 3494.05556 3494.05556 2032.00000 2032.00000
 [21] 3559.08333 2113.13889 1991.50000 4580.52778 4580.52778 2538.41667 4319.08333 3725.72222 3342.61111 3952.00000
 [31] 4473.05556 4473.05556 3503.63889 4106.33333  -56.80556  -56.80556  -56.80556 4120.36111 3342.61111 2922.44444
 [41] 3100.75000 3100.75000 4152.94444 4399.16667 4399.16667 4399.16667 4399.16667 4399.16667 4399.16667 4399.16667
 [51] 4399.16667 2405.08333 2405.08333 2924.38889 4310.52778 4293.22222 4237.13889 4237.13889 4237.13889 3180.02778
 [61] 4037.60000 3823.72222 3191.41667 3191.41667 3330.66667 3961.25000 3952.52778 2732.41667 2732.41667 4894.86111
 [71] 3156.52778 3156.52778 3156.52778 3156.52778 3156.52778 3278.13889 3278.13889 3278.13889 4794.66667 4530.25000
 [81] 4530.25000 4530.25000 4530.25000 2873.11111 3775.69444 2574.47222 2574.47222 3510.13889 2713.02778 4129.50000
 [91] 3130.11111 4987.25000 3098.25000 3663.02778 3521.02778 4285.11111 3225.80556 2311.11111 2311.11111 2337.00000
[101] 2460.13889 4058.44444 4019.41667 3357.08333 3960.83333 4539.58333 3336.00000 3336.00000 3336.00000 2239.50000
[111] 2239.50000  628.22222 3506.36111 3859.11111 3900.97222 3900.97222 3900.97222 3900.97222 3191.41667 4226.44444
[121] 3409.91667 3278.13889 4719.30556 3414.27778 3414.27778 2749.94444 2036.25000 3015.63889 2600.97222 3156.52778
[131] 4070.55556 4207.44444 4207.44444 4207.44444 2640.52778 2640.52778 2309.33333 2390.16667 2390.16667
```

Comment: The raster object that you are displaying is not multiband but, rather single band. Can you show us your code for reading the data? You should be using the raster::stack or raster::brick function to read your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open it using `EVI.all = stack()`, not `raster()`. Then, each band is located as a layer in the stack, so `EVI.all[[1]]` would call the first band (e.g. January) and `EVI.all[[12]]` would call the last (December).

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code:

```
library(raster)
# locate your EVI.all file 
path = '...\\EVI.all.tif'
# to get values of 1st band of EVI.all
EVI.all_1 = raster(path, band = 1)
values(EVI.all_1)
# to get values of 2nd band of EVI.all
EVI.all_2  = raster(path, band =2)
values(EVI.all_2) 
# and so on....
```